# Implement Load Balancing using Ribbon

Tags: load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon, spring-cloud-consul

I am new to spring cloud and microservices. I am planning to implement load balancing on an independent micro service and need understand how to implement load Balancing using zuul api gateway without using feign client and hard coding list of end points available in java or in application.properties file.Most of the sample codes available over internet are hard coding list of servers and using load balancer choose option to get available list of end points to perform load balancing.Please suggest a way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You need service-registry like eureka-server form which zuul will gather information about registered services. If there will be multiple services with same name load balancing will work out of the box.

You can also look at my code example [here](https://github.com/gltomasz/spring-cloud-samples/tree/master/service-failover)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a solution.